# Reducir ibdata1 y ib_logfile0

Tags: mysql

Quiero reducir el tamaño de los ficheros ibdata1 y ib_logfile0 de mi servidor Mysql 5.7
No quiero activar la opción innodb_file_per_table.
Cual seria la mejor opción de reducir el tamaña sin activar innodb_file_per_table?
Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que revisar los parámetros de tu archivo de configuración de mysql (usualmente el archivo de configuración es `mysqld.cnf`) y ver qué tienes configurado en los parámetros `innodb_data_file_path` y `innodb_log_file_size`.

Usualmente el `ibdata1` parte en un default que es de 48MB (hasta donde recuerdo) pero se va agrandando a medida que el contenido de tu base de datos crece. Lo malo es que no decrece cuando borras información. Si quisieras restringir el tamaño máximo de tu tablespace, y tu archivo de configuración dijera, por ejemplo

```
innodb_data_file_path = /ibdata/ibdata1:48M:autoextend
```

Podrías simplemente poner

```
innodb_data_file_path = /ibdata/ibdata1:96M
```

(o sea, no se autoincrementa, pero te das un margen más amplio para que luego no te tire un error de que se llenó el tablespace).

Si el parámetro no aparece, significa que mysql está usando el valor default (de nuevo, puede ser 48M autoextend o 10M autoextend dependiendo de la versión)

Si quisieras en cambio **simplemente reclamar el espacio liberado** por haber borrado una tabla muy grande, tu única opción sería dumpear un respaldo de la base actual, detener el servicio `mysql`, borrar el `ibdata`, reiniciar el servicio y cargar el dump.

---

Respecto al tamaño de los logfiles, si en tu archivo de configuración tuvieses

```
innodb_log_file_size = 48M
```

Podrías cambiarlo a otro tamaño, detener el servicio, borrar los logfiles  y reiniciar el servicio. En este caso yo respaldaría el contenido completo de la carpeta de datos de mysql por si algo sale mal.

Si el parámetro no aparece, significa que está usando el parámetro por defecto.

En general yo te recomendaría ya sea usar `innodb_file_per_table` (que no sé qué le encuentras de malo) o simplemente atachar más almacenamiento a la máquina. **El espacio es barato. La data es valiosa**.

Pero, en fin, si estás decidido a hacerlo, pese a que no es tan buena idea, y lo que quieres es comprobar cómo se hace y cómo resulta con un propósito meramente investigativo, al menos asegúrate de sacar una copia de la carpeta de datos (usualmente `ibdata`).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El tema es que como es un entorno de pruebas he creado y borrado varias veces base de datos (con datos incluidos) y como bien comentas al borrar base de datos enteras el fichero ibdata no reduce su tamaño automáticamente.Al ya tener las bases de datos definitivas y listas para usar queria reducir el tamaño del Ibdata en acorde con lo que tengo ahora.

Comment: Lo que comentas de borrar el ibdata y reiniciar Mysql.
Estos pasos son los que hay que llevar:
-dump de todas las bases de datos de usuario

Comment: -borrar las bases de datos
-borrar los ibdata
-reinciar Mysql
-load las bases de datos

Comment: Los pasos son correctos??
Y las bases de datos de sistema mysql, information_schema, performance_schema hay que hacer algún tipo de actuación con ellas?

Comment: si dumpeas todas las bases y luego cargas todas las bases, todas ellas se restablecen. Hasta donde recuerdo el `information_schema` y  `performance_schema` no tenían almacenamiento físico, sino que se reconstruyen con introspección de las tablas que existen físicamente

Comment: y sobre la base de datos de mysql?